# Add function to button in alertcontroller

Tags: ios, swift, uialertcontroller

I am new to swift and I have followed some tutorial in alert view lesson. I want to add function like call another viewcontroller whenever the alert's button is clicked but i dont know how. so pls help me

```
    func showAlertController(){

    var title : String = "hi!"
    var message : String = NSLocalizedString("Are you feeling well? ", comment:"")
    let cancelButtonTitle = NSLocalizedString("No", comment:"")
    let otherButtonTitle = NSLocalizedString("Yes", comment:"")

    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: .Alert)

    let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: cancelButtonTitle, style: .Cancel){
        action in NSLog("No!!!!")
    }

    let otherAction = UIAlertAction(title: otherButtonTitle, style: .Default){
        action in NSLog("welcome!!! hello back")
    }

    alertController.addAction(cancelAction)
    alertController.addAction(otherAction)
    presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: Have a look at [UIAlertViewController to Present an Alert](http://www.appcoda.com/uialertcontroller-swift-closures-enum/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code:

```
let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: cancelButtonTitle, style: .Cancel){
        action in NSLog("No!!!!")
        let View2 = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("View2") as TwoViewController
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(View2, animated: true)
        
    }
```

and also select your existing view controller and then From the drop down menu select **Edit>Embed in > Navigation Controller**.

After that add a new view controller and create a new Cocoa Class and name it **TwoViewController** SubClass of `UIViewController`.

After that select your new ViewController and Customise it this way from Identity Inspector [image]

May be this can help you.

Comment: thx for ur quick reply, but what i want to know is how to link to another ViewController when the alert button is clicked. in my function, when i press cancel button it will print "No" but what i want to get is link to another view controller when i press button "No"

Comment: I have updated answer and sorry its late because was busy with work.

Comment: I really thank for your help, now it work. i think i used to do like that before but it got some error... but now everything is just too good...